# Postman - Ignoring a request from the runner based on iteration count

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have to run my collection on two different Country levels so I have my iteration set up as one iteration for one country, but some of the endpoints are not country-specific and need not have to run twice.

Is there a way I can avoid running certain endpoints only once in the runner based on iteration?

I tried this way by adding an Iteration Count column in my data.csv

```
if (pm.iterationData.get(“Iteration Count”) === 1) {
  postman.setNextRequest(‘request name1’);
} else {
  postman.setNextRequest(‘request name2’);
}
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Please add collection structure , request , body screen shots and also explain how request for country1 and country2 differs . SetNextRequest executes only after the request in which it is defined even if it is set in prerequest .

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.info.iteration
```

gives the current iteration number (starts as 0 )

```
if (pm.info.iteration === 0) {

postman.setNextRequest(‘request name1’);

} else {

postman.setNextRequest(‘request name2’);

}
```

Also in postman ,you can modify everything in postman through pm object

So you can change pm.request.url

pm.request.body

Etc

SetNextRequest doesn't skip current request , it will get executed after current request is completed.

So what you can do is add a preparation script and do

`postman.setNextRequest(null)` this will ensure there is no next request after executing the current execution , add this  to the two main request

and in preparation request add

```
postman.setNextRequest("country1")

Else 

postman.setNextRequest("country2")
```

Please add the request structure and collection structure so that we can give more correct answer

Comment: This is now resolved with the below in Pre req.                                                                                                                                         if(“value” == pm.iterationData.get(“fieldname”))

{

postman.setNextRequest("Next request");
} Thank you.

Comment: Sorry iteration starts from 0 , so first iteration is 0 and last iteration is n-1